# What is the best way to disable links when on page?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

I have a set of links on a page. The href is driven from a numeric value entered by an admin via WordPress.

```
<div class="medium-3 large-2 large-offset-2 columns">
    <a href="{{ nav.get_field('box_#1_link') }}">
        <button>
            {{ nav.get_field('box_#1_text') }}
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="medium-3 large-2 columns">
    <a href="{{ nav.get_field('box_#2_link') }}">
        <button>
            {{ nav.get_field('box_#2_text') }}
        </button>
    </a>
</div>
```

For example, let's say the first link (box_#1_link) is set to 25. If a user is on www.example.com/members and clicks the first link they will be navigated to www.example.com/members/25.

The problem I'm having is if they click the same link again. They are navigated to www.example.com/members/25/25.

This set of links will be used on many pages, so setting the entire URL path isn't an option.

What is the best way to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: or fix the urls so they point to the right location?

Comment: @epascarello This link exists on many pages, so it's not that simple.

Comment: Check the variable scope. it seems its global and keeps on appending each time. It should be local to the event.

Comment: @indra-uprade It's an advanced custom fields text field, so it's not a full URL, just a number that is entered via the WordPress admin.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if I'm not mistaken nav.get_field('box_#1_link') is a custom template tag, you probably need to go back to the function that handles that and perhaps implement an if block statement. The function is getting called twice and value 25 is getting appended twice as well.

Comment: It's an advanced custom fields text field, so I don't think an if block is relevant in this case.

Comment: Hi Molly, is the assumption that the function is being called twice correct? -- causing the value "25" being appended twice in the href value (e.g. example.com/members/25/25)... I think issue lies there.

Comment: or perhaps when the user click on the link, the loop runs again re-appending the same value.

Comment: No, it's basically just a variable set via the WordPress admin, so it continues to append the variable to the path.